# Cannot upgrade MariaDB Connector/C on Parrot OS

Tags: python, mariadb, parrotsec

Please note very new to ParrotOS + Python.

Error output when trying `pip3 install mariadb` :

```
MariaDB Connector/Python requires MariaDB Connector/C >= 3.3.1, found version 3.1.18
```

I cannot seem to upgrade MariaDB on Connector/C on Parrot OS.
ParrotOS is not supported on : [MariaDB Connectors](https://mariadb.com/downloads/connectors/connectors-data-access/c-connector/) .

I tried the following which also did not work : [Similar StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63628125/error-pip-install-mariadb-on-ubuntu-server?newreg=b2854982b7944657b75bb506121c42a8)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: **1)** Try downloading and installing the debian or ubuntu version from the MariaDB website. Parrot OS is based on debian so it might work. **2)** If none of the packages worked then you can install docker or podman for using an Ubuntu/Debian container and make your development there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Parrot OS is Debian Stable based, you can follow MariDB instructions for Debian 11.

- Install dependencies:

> ```
> $ apt install curl apt-transport-https wget
> ```

- Download and execute repository script (https://mariadb.com/downloads/repo-setup/)

> ```
> $ wget https://dlm.mariadb.com/3/MariaDB/mariadb_repo_setup
> $ chmod +x mariadb_repo_setup
> $ ./mariadb_repo_setup --os-type=debian --os-version=11 --arch=x86_64
> ```

- Install MariaDB connector C libraries

> ```
> $ apt install install libmariadb-dev-compat
> ```

- Finally, install python mariadb:

> ```
> $ pip3 install mariadb
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot man this worked liked a charm! Just note I had to change "./mariadb-repo" to "./mariadb-repo-setup" for it to work.

Comment: oh my bad...typo...edited with proper command now hehe